# Modifying a Wordpress widget - extracting and displaying all the posts in a category

Tags: wordpress, widget

I've been running in circles for like ages trying to edit this widget. Had some trouble formating all that code in here so i will just post a link from pastebin - http://pastebin.com/tdYFAgQD.

What i want and can't achieve, is to display all the posts in a category, in this format (a block with the featured image, then the title then the text), one after another. I want to get rid of that list thingy (that displays x number of posts but in the same window) and have all the post displayed like as i said, one after another in separate blocks.

**Here's a picture that may make the things clearer**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZp6i.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action

To get the 4 blocks to show up like that, you'll have to think more about the HTML / CSS that will be generated. Consider simply getting the 4 divs you want to show up by modifying the loop, then go from there.

Beginning at line 105 in your pastebin is the bit producing those "links" so simply remove these lines of code:

```
<?php if ( $warrior_posts_list_left->post_count > 1) echo '<ul>'; ?>                   
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                    <li>
                                            <span class="icon-file"></span> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php echowarrior_post_title('35'); ?></a>
                                    </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                    <?php $i = $i + 1; endwhile; ?>
                    <?php if ( $warrior_posts_list_left->post_count > 1) echo '</ul>'; ?>
```

Further, you may want to ask your question here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ or on the support forum for the particular wordpress plugin you're modifying http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

Comment: Thanks for the tip @ the list. Going back to the posts, i took as example 4 blocks, i will display the entire category (every single post). I will read about "the loop" to see if i get the things working.
I was having trouble "reading" that widget as (if i'm right) it is wrote in an oop manner.

Comment: Correct, it is Object-Oriented programming, you may also want to read this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Developing_Widgets

Comment: After reading those articles i figured out how to code it ^^. Here is a pastebin link with the working widget - http://pastebin.com/wugixMej .
Thanks mate :D